# clickable links in Div innerhtml

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm drawing a rectangular shape in a div from asp.net code behind and adding innerhtml dynamically in which each content in the innethtml(for eg table/column details) will be placed in a newline.

I want each text in a newline inside the rectangle to be clickable. How can I add it dynamically ib code behind?

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: Why are you doing it that way? ASP.Net is object-oriented, so why reinvent the wheel? But if you don't know how to add clickable links, well, that's pretty basic HTML, about as basic as you can get: <a href="link.aspx">Clickable Text</a>. I would look around for tutorials on HTML.